# how to order by count when joining another table and using 2 fields to count

Tags: mysql, sql

So I am trying to present some data on the screen which includes a count. The count is calculated by two fields startingAT and endingAt.

```
     SELECT * FROM venue
     INNER JOIN plans ON venue.idVenue=plans.endingAt OR venue.idVenue=plans.startingAt 
     WHERE venue.idLocation = 3
```

here's my current query. I want to add the count but where I am struggling is startingAt and endingAT are in the plans table. So my question is how do I count from the joined on table and how do I do count with two fields??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you add some sample data and a desired result? It's not quite clear what you would want the result to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count where one of them are matching. You can do this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN venue.idVenue=plans.endingAt 
             OR venue.idVenue=plans.startingAt
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS NumberOf
FROM venue
INNER JOIN plans 
    ON venue.idVenue=plans.endingAt OR venue.idVenue=plans.startingAt 
WHERE 
    venue.idLocation = 3
```

This will get you a total count. If you want to know per idVenue you could do it with a group by like this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN venue.idVenue=plans.endingAt 
             OR venue.idVenue=plans.startingAt
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS NumberOf,
    venue.idVenue
FROM venue
INNER JOIN plans ON venue.idVenue=plans.endingAt 
      OR venue.idVenue=plans.startingAt 
WHERE 
    venue.idLocation = 3
GROUP BY
    venue.idVenue
```

Or if you just want to count and have all the fields form the venue table. You can do this:

```
SELECT 
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            plans 
        WHERE 
            venue.idVenue=plans.endingAt OR venue.idVenue=plans.startingAt 
    ) AS numberOf,
    venue.*
FROM 
    venue
WHERE 
    venue.idLocation = 3
```

Update:
Then you need to put an alias on the column if you want to order by it. Something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        (
            SELECT 
                COUNT(*)
            FROM
                plans 
            WHERE 
                venue.idVenue=plans.endingAt OR venue.idVenue=plans.startingAt 
        ) AS numberOf,
        venue.*
    FROM 
        venue
    WHERE 
        venue.idLocation = 3
) AS tbl
ORDER BY tbl.numberOf
```

Comment: Hey thank you!! I used second piece of code and it runs but for example idvenue - 1 should have the count of 7 but has the count of 6. is that something on my end?

Comment: one last thing this query was also being used to pull data from table venue. Now it no longer pulls it. How do I add in a SELECT * from venue at the same time?

Comment: @Jordanbaggs : Look at the 3 query

Comment: the third one doesnt seem to order it. do I need to put in ORDER BY count?

Comment: @Jordanbaggs : Yes if you want it to be order

Comment: So just ORDER BY COUNT(*)